# react-native ActivityIndicator in Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

i'm trying to add an ActivityIndicator to my react-native app.
in IOS It works well, also in Android emulator.
but in real Android device its doesn't work.

my try:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

class Spinner extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator
          size="large"
          animating
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Spinner;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}} In the View

Comment: Add this and try once please.
 animating={true}

Comment: I tried in two three devices its working. Can you check in another device.